# No sound in minecraft ubuntu 20.04 LTS fresh install?

Tags: sound, alsa, minecraft

Installed ubuntu 20.04 LTS today, openjdk and openjfx and went to play minecraft. installed it but when i enter the game suddenly no sound what so ever.

I tried: F3+T, F3+S, changing the "drivers=" in alsoft.conf to "drivers=alsa" but nothing.
before i installed ubuntu i was using POP OS (20.04 LTS too) and back then i found a fix but forgot where is was posted and i tried to search it for 3 hours :/ Only what i remember is that i changed the channels in alsoft.conf to "channels=ambi1" and i tried it but doesnt work either.

Also i tried 'lspci' in my terminal and found this:

> Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
> Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 8 Series HD Audio Controller
> Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
> Memory at f7a18000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
> Capabilities: 
> Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
> Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

Any idea out there?

Answer (score 1):

OK, nevermind, started minecraft without sudo and with padsp and somehow now it works? besides that it changed the .minecraft dir from root to home/user?.
Anyways, problem solved.